# How to convert string name to a variable name in R for formulas?

Tags: r

I have this piece of code, given I have already loaded the required packages.

```
cols <- names(survey)

for(col in cols) {
    print(col)
    weights <- information.gain(DIGITAL~col, survey)
    print(weights)
}
```

I know the following statement is not correct. How can I make it correct? Any help I appreciate.

```
weights <- information.gain(DIGITAL~col, survey)
```

Comment: see `?as.formula` with `paste`

Comment: I suppose I could search for a package with that function and then try to guess which one it was, but why should I need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols <- names(survey)

for(col in cols) {
    print(col)
    weights <- information.gain(as.formula(sprintf("DIGITAL~%s, survey", col)))
    print(weights)
}
```

This creates a string with the desired formula and then converts it to a formula using `as.formula`.